# How can I toggle an interface every second in a Bash loop?

Tags: bash, for-loop, ifconfig, network-interface

I want to put an interface down and up every 1 second for 80 times, how can I implement this by a bash script?

Something like this?

```
COUNT = 80
for n in $(seq -w 1 $COUNT); do
    case $n in   
    [1,3,5,7,9....79]*) # I don't know how to represent the odd value only
       ifconfig veth1 down
       sleep 1
       ;;
    [2,4,6,8,10....80]*)
       ifconfig veth1 up
       sleep 1
       ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? If not, what error do you get? What's the expected and actual output, if any? Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COUNT=40
for n in $(seq -w 1 $COUNT); do
  ifconfig veth1 down
  sleep 1
  ifconfig veth1 up
  sleep 1
done
```

Or if you really want to count to 80:

```
COUNT=80
for n in $(seq -w 1 $COUNT); do
  case $n in
    *[13579])
     ifconfig veth1 down
     ;;
    *)
     ifconfig veth1 up
     ;;
  esac
  sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Toggle a flag:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i = 1, flag = 0; i <= 80; i++))
do
    if ((flag ^= 1))
    then
        ifconfig veth1 down    # odd
    else
        ifconfig veth1 up
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: +1 for finding a use for a *bitwise exclusive OR* in a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

use % operator. like the following, replace the echo with the commands you want

```
count=0
while [ $count -lt 80 ]
do
    if (( $count % 2 == 0 ))
    then
        echo 'aaa'
    else
        echo 'bbb'
    fi

    count=$(( $count + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: `while (( count < 80 ))` and `(( count++ ))` but wouldn't you really rather let Bash maintain the counter? `for ((count = 0; count < 80; count++))`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the bashisms, you can make your code much more concise through the use of various expansions available in Bash. For example:

```
for i in {1..80}; do
    case $((i % 2)) in
        0) ifconfig veth1 down ;;
        1) ifconfig veth1 up   ;;
    esac
    sleep 1
done
```

The magic here is the `{1..80}` sequence expression, coupled with the modulo operator to determine whether the number is odd or even. If your version of Bash doesn't support sequence expressions for any reason, just use `$(seq 1 80)` instead.

Comment: Sequence expressions were introduced in Bash 3 almost 8 years ago.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson You're right...it was the sequence expression *increment* that was added in Bash 4. Since my example doesn't use sequence increments, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sequence expressions are nice as far as they go, but they don't seem to be able to use variables.  That is, `c=4; echo {1..$c}` does not return `1 2 3 4`, but `{1..4}`.  You would need to `eval` this to expand it.  And if `eval` is the answer.....  So anyway, +1 for `$((i % 2))`, but -1 for `{1..80}` because of the loss of flexibility.